# Importing ArrayListMultimap into IntelliJ - Java

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I imported the Guava MultiMap library into IntelliJ but when i try to use the MultiMap interface

```
Multimap<String, BlockingQueue<String>> addBlock = new ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

the create is not activate. It is coloured in red.

This is the import statement i used

```
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a static factory method, not a constructor. Remove the `new` keyword:

```
Multimap<String, BlockingQueue<String>> addBlock = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Comment: Thanks @shmosel this is the first time i am using it, and i clearly over looked the fact that is was a static factory method.